# SheetJS shows blank rows

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

Im using SheetJS when i upload the file xlsx using the method

```
_file(file) {
   /* Boilerplate to set up FileReader */
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
      /* Parse data */
      const bstr = e.target.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:'binary'});
      /* Get first worksheet */
      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      /* Convert array of arrays */
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1});
      /* Update state */
      this.data = data;
      this.cols = make_cols(ws['!ref']);
     };
   reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

I got some of the cell that has data but it includes some of the rows that has no data how to remove it? I only want to see rows that has data. TIA

Answer (score 7):

In order to remove the rows without any data you can use the option `blankRows: false`, like this:

```
const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1, blankRows: false});
```

From what I noticed, this option doesn't work together with option `defval`, so if you want to have a default option for some empty cells, but to remove blank rows, you'll have to write a custom function.
There is an open issue about this bug in here: [sheet_to_json does not skip blank rows](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/1078)

Comment: I noticed that "blankrows" should be all lower case since JavaScript is case sensitive. I used "blankRows" in my code but it didn't work for me. I then checked the Sheet.min.js file and found that this option is all lower case.

Comment: what about blank columns ? how remove those ?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the previous comment by Naupad,
setting the attribute `blankRows` all in lowercase works as expected...

```
data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
    header:1,
    blankrows: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a problem like this, defval and blankrows does not meet my condition, because defval also read empty rows with border while blankrows is skipping empty cell in a row, so i create some function to iterate the output sheetdata to a new data array see below.

```
// body...

 /* var sd= XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws,{header:1,defval:""}); */
 /* var sheetdata = sheetjs_cleanEmptyRows(sd) */
 function sheetjs_cleanEmptyRows(sd) {
    const data = []

        for (var row = 0; row < sd.length; row++) {

              var i = sd[row].length;
              var j = 0;

            for ( var cell = 0; cell < sd[row].length; cell++){

                if (sd[row][cell].length == 0 ) { j++}
            }
          if (j < i) {
            data.push(sd[row]);
          }

        }
        return data;
 }
```